# Basic Change Set questions

Tags: change-set

I will be using change sets for the first time to deploy changes from a SDBX to a Test Environment. I have a few questions regarding how this is to be done and am hoping experts here can help.

1) How do I move all modified custom object and its fields by providing their details?
2) I have deleted a few custom objects and fields. Can I simply provide the name of the deleted objects and fields in the change set and will it delete the corresponding objects in the test environment when deployed?
3)Some objects have been renamed. Is it like a modification and must be included in a change set or do I have to keep anything in mind?
3)Users email address have been changed, will I be able to pack these changes also into change set? What will I have to select in the tool to include user related changes?

Apologies if these have been answered already.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How do I move all modified custom object and its fields by providing their details?

Starting from the source org, select the elements from the Change Set user interface, then "Upload" the Change Set to the target org, then "Deploy" the Change Set in the target org.

> 2) I have deleted a few custom objects and fields. Can I simply provide the name of the deleted objects and fields in the change set and will it delete the corresponding objects in the test environment when deployed?

No. Change Sets can only create and update metadata. There are other tools you could be using, but Change Sets is not one of those tools that can delete metadata. This is one reason why you should eventually consider moving to [Unlocked Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/working-with-modular-development-and-unlocked-packages-part-1.html).

> 3)Some objects have been renamed. Is it like a modification and must be included in a change set or do I have to keep anything in mind?

Yes. Change Sets can rename objects, fields, classes, etc, so long as they came from the same common org (typically production). You must make sure that any and all affect code, formulas, etc reference the new names.

> 3)Users email address have been changed, will I be able to pack these changes also into change set? What will I have to select in the tool to include user related changes?

No, you can't deploy users to other orgs, which are more like "data" rather than "metadata" (Change Sets only support the latter). Use the Apex Data Loader or another tool to update those users in other orgs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sfdcfox for the detailed explanation.